# NFSv3 Exporting directories with binded subdirectories

Tags: nfs, mount, export

I've been scratching my head regarding this and thought I'd post it to see if I was missing anything obvious!

The scenario is this:

The server contains a very large folder called "Programmes" which is a LVM volume and is shared over the network (mixed between Ubuntu and OSX) with all users granted R/W access.

A webcam has been fitted to our studio (I'm writing from a radio station in London) and FTPs images to a user account on the server (`/home/webcam`).

I'd like to bind the `/home/webcam` directory under Programmes so that it is accessible to the network when programmes is exported.

I've done the following in fstab:

```
#LVM Disk
UUID_OF_LVM /media/Programmes ext3 errors=remount ro,users,user,relatime

#Bind Web Cam directory and then remount with new RO options
/home/webcam /media/Programmes/Web_Cam none bind,user 0 0
/media/Programmes/Web_Cam /media/Programmes/Web_Cam none remount,ro 0 0

#Bind to export directory and use rbind to include submounts
/media/Programmes /export/Programmes bind rbind
```

In my /etc/exports:

```
/export/Programmes 10.0.2.0/255.255.255.0(nohide,fsid=0,async,all_squash,anonu id=1000,anongid=1000,insecure,no_subtree_check,rw, crossmnt)
```

I can see the Web-Cam folder on the clients but it is empty. I suspect that is an issue with user permissions since I'm exporting a users home directory (coincidently, on Ubuntu it has a lock on the directory)

Answer (score 3):

NFS does not "share folders" (it is not SMB/CIFS). It exports whole file systems. You have to specify which file systems you want to be exported via NFS. If you mount or link a file system within an exported file system, it will not inheiret the export, you have to explicitly export it as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for requires NFS version 4:

> NFS version 4 servers create and maintain a pseudo-file system, which provides clients with seamless access to all exported objects on the server. Prior to NFS version 4, the pseudo-file system did not exist. Clients were forced to mount each shared server file system for access.

-- [File-System Namespace in NFS Version 4](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-1634/rfsrefer-136/index.html)